# Add project member with Firebase CLI

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

Is it possible to add a member to a Firebase project with Firebase CLI ? Or with a Firebase API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with Firebase CLI or [Firebase Management API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest) but [Google Cloud IAM API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest) might be useful. I have not tried it myself but you can try adding a new principal with `Firebase Admin` or `Firebase Viewer` roles.

Comment: The `gcloud` CLI also seems to have this option, although I never used it myself: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#iam-grant-single-role-gcloud

Comment: I think it's same as [Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/setIamPolicy) so that should work :D